# How to create a loading screen between angularJs routes

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create a loading screen with an animated gif when routing in my AngularJs app.

Is it possible to make something generic for this ?

Answer (score 4):

There definitely is.

[$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route)

Check out the events available to you from the $route service.

$routeChangeStart, $routeChangeSuccess, and $routeChangeError will be the most useful. You can listen for these easily on the $rootScope and implement whatever logic you need to show a loading animation or otherwise.